# Is there an Android build flag to check for APK versus Instant App version of an App

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Just like `BuildConfig.FLAVOR` and `BuildConfig.DEBUG` is there a build flag to check at runtime for the APK version or the Instant App version of an Android application ?

Or is there another way to get the information ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add to the module `build.gradle` the dependency : `implementation 'com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.0.0'` then you will be able to use the function `InstantApps.isInstantApp(this)`.

Please note that you must use Maven Google by changing your repositories in the project `build.gradle` :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    ...
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

[Android Instant Apps API reference](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/reference.html)

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to use `PackageManager.isInstantApp()` :

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/instantapps/PackageManagerCompat.html#isInstantApp()

Or, a regular (non-appcompat version) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#isInstantApp()

Also has an override which accepts package name as a string, which allows to check other apps, if permissions allow.

Comment: This method only exists on api level 26+; BUT will be the right way

Comment: I found this method but now is in a different object InstantApps.isInstantApp(context), thanks for the intel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can determine whether the current app is Installed App or Instant app.First of all add the dependency in your feature module build.gradle

```
api "com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.0.0"
```

Match you project level build.gradle with this

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    jcenter()
}...
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    jcenter()
}
}
```

Finally at runtime you may write

```
if (InstantApps.isInstantApp(this)) {
        // Do something like, show install button
    } else {
        // Do something like, hide install button
    }
```