# putExtra not transferring data when using setAction and setData

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, android-deep-link

The following piece of code successfully transfers the putExtra value when the app is not running in the `instant` version. However, when I switch to the instant module, the intent does not transfer it. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I tried going through the instant apps FAQ and saw some sample instant apps code, but couldn't find a solution.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
String packageName = "com.example";
String className = "com.example.InfoActivity";
if(InstantApps.isInstantApp(getApplicationContext()))
{
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/instant/info"));
}
else {
    intent.setClassName(packageName, className);
}
intent.putExtra("value", 2);
startActivity(intent);
```

The links have been mapped to URLs, and the activity opens, however the data is not passed through.

Comment: Try to catch the `ActivityNotFoundException` exception. This exception is thrown when no application can handle the `ACTION_VIEW` event.

Comment: The activity is found by the app, and is opening it, but the data is not going through. There is no `ActivityNotFoundExceptions`

Comment: Have you added the `build.gradle` the dependency : implementation `'com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.0.0'`?

Comment: @jess yeah the dependancy is in the `build.gradle` of the baseFeature module. The version is 1.1.0 though.

Comment: Have you already checked this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309515/is-there-an-android-build-flag-to-check-for-apk-versus-instant-app-version-of-an)?

Comment: @jess yep. I'm doing everything they've mentioned: using google's maven as well as implementing the instant apps library.

Comment: It's probably more reliable to add these extras as query parameters to your URL. Since the intent goes through different steps for an instant app (Chrome, Google Play Services, etc...), probably the intent extras are lost.

Comment: @HassanIbraheem you're absolutely right. The technique you mentioned worked. Could you please write it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Advait S, could you try to run your code on O+ device and see if this works?
I was able to successfully transfer data through intent extras on O+ devices, but this doesn't work for me on pre-O.

Comment: @JuliaK Yes, I have the same issue. I ended up going with Hassan's solution of passing the extra values via query params in URL (example.com/instant/info?key=value) and getting the URI in the receiving activity.